# Android : Can I Modify AdUnitId using edittext..?

Tags: java, android

Android : Can I Modify AdUnitId using edittext..?

i have error with this code
    public Button but2;

```
public void init1() {
    but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.simpan1);
    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText a =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
            AdView  b =(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView0);
            b.setAdUnitId(a.getText().toString());


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you have to take button click event and getText() on click after enter value in edittext,
or you can override Edittext's oneditorsetOnEditorActionListener method.

Comment: I've made click button but still error when in run on android

    public Button but2;

    public void init1() {
        but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.simpan1);
        but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText a =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
                AdView  b =(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView0);
                b.setAdUnitId(a.getText().toString());


            }
        });

    }

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

after enter text in edittext click on button...

```
public void init1() {

    EditText a =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    AdView  b =(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView0);
    but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.simpan1);
    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            b.setAdUnitId(a.getText().toString());


        }
    });

}
```